# How to run videos smoother on chromium on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am working on a project where I am running chromium browser (on Raspberry Pi 3) in kiosk mode (aka fullscreen mode). On boot, the browser open up in fullscreen, and runs my html file that I have saved locally with pictures and videos. What that html file does, is a slideshow of pictures and videos using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. When the slideshow starts, the videos are really laggy and it affects the marquee that I have on screen. I tried to run YouTube and Other videos, and no problem at all. If you have an idea please help